# opening a .mat file in python for using in matlab

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymatlab

I am trying to open a .MAT file the file name is MNIST.mat and it is located in following folder 
/home/debian/cs640 machine learning/assignment5
here is a script which I wrote following some search on internet what I want to do is open the file and save it as excel

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os
from mat4py import loadmat
os.getcwd()
mat=loadmat('/home/debian/cs640 machine learning/assignment5\MNIST.mat')
print (mat)
```

~

but currently I am getting error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./script1.py", line 5, in
>   
>       mat=loadmat('/home/debian/cs640 machine learning/assignment5\MNIST.mat')   File
>   "/home/debian/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mat4py/loadmat.py",
>   line 417, in loadmat
>       fd = open(filename, 'rb') FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/debian/cs640 machine
>   learning/assignment5\MNIST.mat'

so why is this error coming in my program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up Unix and DOS directory separators.  You are using Linux, which uses Unix-style `/` for directory separators.  Windows used the DOS-style `\` for directory separators.  Your file location has a mix of both.  Just change:

```
'assignment5\MNIST.mat'
```

To

```
'assignment5/MNIST.mat'
```

Answer (score 0):

The program is not able to find the file. check the path or name of the file. 
you have space in your directory name cs640 machine learning. change it to cs640_machine_learning. It might work.